# Unity DI in Windows Forms with child forms

Tags: c#, winforms, unity-container

I am using Unity DI in a windows forms application.  It is working so far resolving dependencies to the main form in program.cs like this:

```
    static void Main()
{
    IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
    container.AddNewExtensionIfNotPresent<EnterpriseLibraryCoreExtension>();
    container.RegisterType<IAccountService, AccountService>();
    container.RegisterType<IAccountRepository, AccountRepository>();

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(container.Resolve <MainForm>());
}
```

My problem is when my MainForm tries creates a child form:

```
    ChildForm childForm = new ChildForm();
    childForm.Show();
```

I am getting an error because I'm trying to use constructor injection and I'm not passing in the constructor arguments. I also tried using setter injection with the [Dependency] attribute but that didn't work either.  How should I accomplish this?  I could have my main form have all the dependencies and pass the required objects to the child forms, but if I end up having many child forms then the main form would be messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for Unity to inject the constructor arguments, you'll need to use the container to resolve the child form.  So you'll need to hold a reference to your container somewhere, then call:

```
ChildForm childForm = container.Resolve<ChildForm>();
```

This will allow Unity to evaluate the ChildForm constructors and inject the appropriate dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize I could make the container a public property of program.cs and reference it in my forms.  Your answer helped me to see it.

Comment: this smells awfully like service locator

Answer (score 3):

In the comment above you mentioned "mak[ing] the container a public property of program.cs".

Don't do that.

If your form has a dependency on the container, treat it like any other dependency.

- add the container to the container.
- Use either a property or ctor injection to give the form access to the container.

  ```
  static void Main()
  {

      IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

      container
          .RegisterType<MainForm>()
          .RegisterInstance<IUnityContainer>(container);
  ```

.

```
    public partial class MainForm: Form
    {
        [Dependency]
        public IUnityContainer Container { get; set; }
```